# Handling Monggose schema change handling from string to string Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My current doc is like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ece69df332eb0000d34e12"),
    "parent" : "P1",
    "hierarchy" : {},
    "hidden" : false,
    "type" : "xyz",
    "name" : "Mike",
    "code" : "M110",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-09-07T01:21:33.965Z"),
    "__v" : 3,
    "job_id" : "ca50fdf0-6904-11e6-b9af-1b0ea5d7f792"
}
```

now i want to have job_id as array instead. So i changed the field type to array in model schema. Now when I try to update the existing docs with some changes.
Document before saving looks like this

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55ece69df332eb0000d34e12"),
        "parent" : "P1",
        "hierarchy" : {},
        "hidden" : false,
        "type" : "xyz",
        "name" : "Mike",
        "code" : "M110",
        "date" : ISODate("2015-09-07T01:21:33.965Z"),
        "__v" : 3,
        "job_id" : ["ca50fdf0-6904-11e6-b9af-1b0ea5d7f792",
                    "f1f04a95-42fa-41e5-a2c6-89c52c9c63f2"
                    ]
    }
```

so when i call model.save() method i'm getting following error:

```
{ [MongoError: The field 'job_id' must be an array but is of type String in document {_id: ObjectId('55ece69df332eb0000d34e12')}]
  name: 'MongoError',
  code: 16837,
  err: 'The field \'job_id\' must be an array but is of type String in document {_id: ObjectId(\'55ece69df332eb0000d34e12\')}' }
```

What is the best way to handle this??

Comment: Can you post the declaration of job_id in your model schema?

Comment: @dyouberg it was 'SchemaTypes.OPTIONAL_STRING' earlier,
then changed to '[SchemaTypes.OPTIONAL_STRING]'